# JSON Schema: require property if at least one nested item has another property set

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have this data structure:

```
{
  "ELEMENTS": {
    "element_1": {
      "requiredPropIfAtLeastOneFlag": "",
      "ITEMS": {
        "item_1": {
          "flag": "flag foo"
        },
        "item_2": {
          "flag": "flag bar"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to make `requiredPropIfAtLeastOneFlag` mandatory if *at least one* of the `ITEMS` has the `flag` key set.

I have tried the following schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "ELEMENTS": {
      "type": "object",
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "patternProperties": {
        "^[a-zA-Z](\\w*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$": {
          "type": "object",
          "additionalProperties": false,
          "properties": {
            "requiredPropIfAtLeastOneFlag": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "ITEMS": {
              "type": "object",
              "additionalProperties": false,
              "patternProperties": {
                "^[a-zA-Z](\\w*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "additionalProperties": false,
                  "properties": {
                    "flag": {
                      "type": "string"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "if": {
            "properties": {
              "ITEMS": {
                "patternProperties": {
                  "^[a-zA-Z](\\w*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$": {
                    "required": [
                      "flag"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "then": {
            "required": [
              "requiredPropIfAtLeastOneFlag"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and it works, but only if *both* `item_1` and `item_2` have the `flag` property set.
In other words, the following data is considered valid, even if `item_1` has the `flag` set:

```
{
  "ELEMENTS": {
    "element_1": {
      // "requiredPropIfAtLeastOneFlag": "",
      "ITEMS": {
        "item_1": {
          "flag": "flag foo"
        },
        "item_2": {
          // "flag": "flag bar"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

All the properties of `ELEMENTS` and `ITEMS` are dynamic, therefore the `"additionalProperties": false` configuration and the `patterProperties` regular expression.

I haven't been able to figure out how to invalidate the data if at least one `item` has the `flag` set and `requiredPropIfAtLeastOneFlag` is missing.

I used https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net for testing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead of the `if`/`then`. `patternProperties` ensures that none of the properties have "flag". If that is false, then we know that at least one of the properties has "flag", which can be expressed by negating the expression with `not`.

```
"not": {
  "patternProperties": {
    "^[a-zA-Z](\\w*[a-zA-Z0-9])?$": {
      "not": { "required": ["flag"] }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible (unless you explicitly spelled out all combinations of properties, which won't work for you since you are using a pattern to express them). However, if you can restructure your data so that the 'item' properties are represented in an array, you can use the `contains` and `minContains` keywords to indicate that at least one of the items must have a matching property.