# How to create a json schema that enforces that one child property has a field set

Tags: jsonschema

I have the following JSON Schema:

```
   "EntityDefinition": {
        "type": "object",
        "title": "An entity definition",
        "required": [ "pluralName" ],
        "properties": {
          "pluralName": { "type": "string" },
          "sitemap": { "type": "string" },
          "comment": { "type": "string" },
          "forms": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {
              "type": "object",
              "$ref": "#/definitions/FormDefinition"
            }
          },
          "attributes": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": {
              "type": "object",
              "$ref": "#/definitions/AttributeDefinition"
            }
          }

        }
      }
```

which allows the wildcard names of the attributes object

```
{
  "attributes":{
    "field1":{},
    "field2":{}
  }
}
```

Is there a way to specify that at least one of the child fields, `field1` or `field2` in the example, have a property "isPrimaryField" given?

```
{
  "attributes":{
    "field1":{},
    "field2":{ "isPrimaryField":true}
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you need the object equivalent to the `contains` keyword, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I've opened an issue on the JSON Schema GitHub repo for this. https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/1077 it's always nice to have a use case in the wild to illustrate its need. 

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66265656/json-schema-require-property-if-at-least-one-nested-item-has-another-property-s, asked just a few days ago.

Comment: This can be done. I answered the question @Ether identified as duplicate. You can use the same strategy, just use `additionalProperties` instead of `patternProperties` from that answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can require this isPrimaryField property by defining a schema for you attribute properties like so:

```
  definitions:
    EntityDefinition:
      type: object
      title: An entity definition
      required:
        - attributes
      properties:
        attributes:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/definitions/AttributesWithPrimaryPresent'
          not:
            $ref: '#/definitions/AttributesWithoutPrimaryPresent'
    AttributesWithPrimaryPresent:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        $ref: '#/definitions/PrimaryOrSecondary'
    AttributesWithoutPrimaryPresent:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        $ref: '#/definitions/SecondaryFieldAttributeMap'
    PrimaryOrSecondary:
      oneOf:
      - $ref: '#/definitions/PrimaryFieldAttributeMap'
      - $ref: '#/definitions/SecondaryFieldAttributeMap'
    PrimaryFieldAttributeMap:
      type: object
      properties:
        isPrimaryField:
          type: boolean
      required:
      - isPrimaryField
    SecondaryFieldAttributeMap:
      type: object
      not:
        type: object
        properties:
          isPrimaryField:
            type: boolean
        required:
        - isPrimaryField
```

Note: You don't need to set additionalProperties to true in schemas, it is true when omitted

This will require that >= 1 attribute has isPrimaryField set.

If you need only one map to have this property, then my suggestion is to make a separate attribute property, like:
primary_field_addtribute = {}
That will allow you to require qty 1. Do not store that attribute in attributes. Attributes becomes non_primary_attributes.

Comment: How are you relating this question to OpenAPI?  It's a pure JSON Schema question.

Comment: Hi, OpenAPI is a json schema implementor.
I will update it to be jsonSchema only.

Comment: (pedantic me coming out) OpenAPI is a JSON Schema _consumer_.  I am an implementor.